# Local notifications start alone when opening the application

Tags: android

I'm working with AlarmManager to be able to send notifications at some time. (This function is done without problems). My problem is when I open my application a few seconds later it starts the notification and I do not want that to happen.

Annex the code that makes the notifications work.

**class AlarmReceiver**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, OfertasActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_iconbuscandoando)
            .setContentTitle("BuscandoAndo")
            .setWhen(when)
            .setContentText("Hey! Ve las ofertas que tenemos el dia de hoy para ti!")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Hey! Ve las ofertas que tenemos el dia de hoy para ti!"))
            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 2000)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{500, 500, 500})
            .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "/" + R.raw.alerta))
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

}

**AndroidManifest**

```
        <receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceiver.AlarmReceiver"/>
```

**function in the Mainactivity class**

```
 private void createAlarm() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,8);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
```

**command to call the function in the OnCreate**

```
        createAlarm();
```

In advance thanks and hope I can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the alarm inside onCreate, so each time MainActivity is opened, you set it.
Then the question is why is being triggered some moments later instead of later early in the morning?
For what I can see you are setting it for the current day in a previous time, if an alarm is set to an expired time is triggered as soon as the system can.
Change the time for some minutes later of your device current time and you will get it working.